# Invalid Security Certificate?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, security

On careers.stackoverflow.com , I click on "file CV", and Firefox gives me this error:

```
careers.stackoverflow.com uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown.
(Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)
```

Of course, I could be the subject of a man-in-the-middle attack, but I suspect there is a more prosaic cause!

#### Update

I'm seeing Comodo as the issuer, but Firefox is still saying:
"the certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown."

It works OK in IE7.

Would it help if I post more details of the cert I'm seeing?

#### Working!

It's working OK now.

thanks, Geoff :)

Comment: The issuer is Stack Overflow?

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: No-repo for me. (Using FF 3.0.14 on Ubuntu 9.04.)

Answer (score 3):

We have installed Comodo root and intermediate certificates - could somebody having this issue please verify if this has resolved the issue.

**UPDATE**
Received five new certificates from COMODO our SSL Provider, installed all of them including Trusted Root Certification and Intermediate Certification Authorities

Installing these required a server reboot.  It should be working now.

Comment: I'm still seeing the error.  :(

Comment: I get the error when using Firefox on Windows.  IE 8 gives me no errors.

Comment: Roger that, ChrisC.  IE 7 gives me no errors, either.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good site to make sure the cert and chain is installed correctly - http://www.digicert.com/help/

And I have had problems with Firefox caching an invalid certificate which makes it real difficult to troubleshoot these problems.

Answer (score 0):

I got this yesterday, too.  It appears to be fixed now.

SO team probably left the self-signed test cert on it by accident.

Comment: still not working for me - possibly some caching going on (??). I'll try again tomorrow.  thanks :)