# Is something wrong with the stack exchange root certificate?

Tags: bug, security, ssl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Better HTTPS support for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites)

I usually visit Stackoverflow through https. Since a few days, Safari will warn me that it can't verify the identity of the server because the certificate is invalid. A little experiment just told me that Firefox is giving the same warning.

A similar question [has been asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27545/invalid-security-certificate) in 2009, but then the certificate was not trusted rather than simply invalid.

What is going on, and when can we expect it to be fixed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning is given because the certificate used is a wildcard cert for `*.stackexchange.com` sites only, and `stackoverflow.com` doesn't match that domain name (obviously).

Otherwise the cert looks in perfect order.

My guess is that using `https://stackoverflow.com` isn't officially supported; it just happens to work because the front-end webserver acts a virtual host server for all stackexchange.com sites, including those that *do* support HTTPS such as https://openid.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I would like to know whether it's true that using stackoverflow over https is unsupported. And if so, why it has worked for so long.

Comment: @Julian It's [not supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69171/why-doesnt-the-stack-overflow-team-fix-the-firesheep-style-cookie-theft). And I've heard of people seeing this exact warning before, so I'm not sure why you weren't seeing it, but it's not new

Comment: Thank you for affirming that.

Comment: @Julian: See [my answer on another question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116798) for why this happens.